# Updating this one particular field is breaking my code, no idea why

Tags: apex, field-update, scheduled-job

I have a scheduled class to check every day if any orders have a balance due and the late date was reached, to add interest. I have a payment due date, but then I also have an overdue date that's by default, a day after the payment due date. But, after it adds interest, it shouldn't add interest again until another month. So, I use the overdue date field for that -- after I add interest, I want to extend the overdue date by one month.

Here is the execute function

```
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Order2__c> latePayments){
    for(Order2__c order : latePayments){
        system.debug(order.id);
    }
        setInterest.setAmount(latePayments);
    for(order2__c order : latePayments){
       //order.overdue_date__c = order.overdue_date__c.addMonths(1);
       //update order;
    }
}
```

This works perfectly with this...

```
public class setInterest {

public static void setAmount(List<Order2__c> orders){
    for(Order2__c o : orders){
        System.debug('Interest set for this order');
        System.debug('Payment Due: ' + o.Payment_Due__c);
        o.interest_payment_overdue__c = o.interest_payment_overdue__c + (o.payment_due__c * 0.015);
        System.debug('Interest Due: ' + o.interest_payment_overdue__c);
        //o.overdue_date__c = o.overdue_date__c.addMonths(1);
        o.interestStarted__c = true;
        update o;
        system.debug(o.id);
    }
}

}
```

that commented bit, where I update the overdue date, is the problem. Omitting it here, it works exactly like I want. If I add that in, one of the logs shows that I'm trying to reference a null object, but gives no indication of what line or anything, and the code doesn't work properly (ie. the interest doesn't update).

I have tried placing it in different places, such as where it is commented out in the execute method....I have no idea how to update this field. Thoughts? Apologies if I left out anything useful, I don't quite know what to look for here...quite baffled.

Comment: Do not use a DML inside of a loop. That's simply asking for trouble down the road.

Comment: It appears that you forgot to query the Overdue Date field in your start method, or the overdue date field was null for some reason.

Comment: @sfdcfox Thank you!!! I moved the update as update latePayments in the execute.

Comment: IT WORKS!!! I feel dumb, I should have caught that. Thank you for kindly and politely pointing out the obvious :)

Comment: That is incredibly strange, however, that I could upate interestStarted__c without adding it to the query. Adding overdue to the query worked, but I'm now very curious as to why interestStarted__c was fine without it added....

Comment: You're welcome. Sometimes you just need a second pair of eyes. Also, have you tried [rubber duck programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging)? Sometimes just talking through the problem aloud can produce results.

Comment: As for InterestStarted__c, you didn't use the original value, so you didn't need to query it. You only need to query fields that you need to get the value from. In this case, you simply assigned a new value to it (true).

Comment: I did not know that! That makes sense, but I always thought if you wanted to use any field at all, you had to include it. What a great new insight.